# Is it possible in .net to declare variable by class string name, but no direct class name?

Tags: string, variables, text, declare

I want a magic to happen like that...

```
class SomeClass {}

public static void main()

    MagicFunctionOrMacrosOrSomethingThatGetTypeOf("SomeClass") some_var = null;<br />
}
```

Maybe it's crazy, but is it possible?
I need it to avoid crazy large switch case, because has a lot of classes, but at certain point of code is unable to tell what of the classes to create.

Let's have an example:
I have base class:
class baseCLASS {}

have a lot of child classes:
class class1 : baseCLASS {}
class class2 : baseCLASS {}
...
class classn : baseCLASS {}

have some flag that comes from outside to events handler:
string class_name; //actually i use int flag that should have connected with string names in dictionary.

have forced to make this:

```
   switch(class_name)

   case "class1":
      class1 some_class = new class1();
      some_class.RunHandler();
      break;
   case "class2":
      class2 some_class = new class2();
      some_class.RunHandler();
      break;
   case "classn":
      classn some_class = new classn();
      some_class.RunHandler();
      break;
   }
```

I want to replace that large switch statement by something like this:

```
MagicFunctionOrMacrosOrSomethingThatGetTypeOf(class_name) some_var = null;
... some initialization actions with some_var
some_var.Build();
some_var.RunHandler();
```

oh my...

Comment: I see five tags here, but none close to what is being asked...

Comment: sorry, but i don't even know what tags could describe such weird thing<br />but if see the question words, all that tags fits the question

Comment: You have to declare the variable with a base type that fits all of the possibilities. In the worst case, this is `object`. It could be `dynamic`. How are you planning on creating the object?

Comment: How would you then use the variable if it is statically typed but the type name can vary? On the other hand, `dynamic` seems to fit your needs, no switches involved.

Comment: then i have a problem with initializing that variable with specific child class. let me update the question for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. Given user input, you want to instantiate an object of a varying class. For this, you want a mapping between user input and .NET type name. For the first: you can use a convention -- ensure that the type name matches the input; or you can use a `Dictionary<string,type>`, and populate it; or you can attach an attribute to each class, showing which "verb" it handles. Once you've done that, you can use `Activator.CreateInstance` to (at runtime) create an instance of your unknown class. This returns `object`.
2. Calling methods on the unknown object. Either define a base class or common interface for the classes (e.g. `IRunnable` or something), or use `dynamic`, which gives you duck typing.

Comment: thanks, the thing with Activator.CreateInstance exactly what i wanted